# Proof that the direct sum of two cyclic modules is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, cyclic-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem

I've seen the proof that for gcd$(m,n)=1$ the product $\mathbb{Z}/{n \mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}/{m \mathbb{Z}}$ is cyclic since it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/{nm \mathbb{Z}}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

But now I am asked to show that the external direct sum $\mathbb{Z}/{n \mathbb{Z}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/{m \mathbb{Z}}$ is cyclic iff gcd$(m,n)=1$ and I'm not sure why this is true. It seems to be related enough but I could do with some help.

Comment: What do you think the difference between the direct product and sum is?

Comment: @Randall poses the right question. More generally, if you say to yourself "X seems to be related to Y" (as you did in your post with X being "product" and Y being "external direct sum"), you should literally compare X and Y! What is the same between the two definitions, and what is different?

Comment: @directdeltafunk By my understanding, they're the same since we have a finite number of factors so, the proof is likely identical..